# How does firebase parse the iosMinimumVersion setting in a deep link?

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking

I have an app where I updated the version in the store to "2.5.X" where previously it was "2.4.X".  My deep links, which are created via the firebase api, had the iosMinimumVersion set to "2.4.48" and stopped working with the app once I changed the version.  It would keep opening the connect store and ask to install the app, even though it was already installed.

How does it parse the version string?  is it only looking at the last part and ignoring the rest?  As a quick test I made a link and set the minimum value to "2.5.1" and it worked as expected and opened my app with the correct data.